Attach JWT Token to ASP.NET MVC controller actions
I am busy testing solutions for a integration between multiple projects where a JWT token is stored in session storage for an ASP.NET MVC application. I am in need of the next steps I need to take as this is the first time doing this.
The token gets set like this in my ControllerAction
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Token", result);

The token has a claim of Role that we need to authorize users for certain controller actions.
How can I use this token automatically when a controller action gets used for the Authorization as with the following examples?
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public IActionResult AdminAction()
{
   return View();
}

[Authorize]
public IActionResult UserAction()
{
   return View();
}


"Role requirements can also be expressed using the Policy syntax, where a developer registers a policy at application startup as part of the Authorization service configuration. " You can have a look at Role-based authorization in ASP.NET Core to know more.
